# How to make use of `template` section in kurfile properly?

Tags: yaml, deep-learning

**The problem**

I tried to experiment on the use of `template`, by adding a `template` section to `mnist.yml`.

I did it trying to mimic a short example below: 
[image]

**My attempts are here**: (rest of `mnist.yml` and `mnist-defaults.yml` are untouched), the original files of mnist to be [found here](https://github.com/deepgram/kur/blob/master/examples/mnist.yml)

[image]

Then I got the following error: 
[image]

---

response to Adam's answer below:

After updated to kur 0.5.2, the codes are here, the `mnist-defaults.yml` is untouched:

[image]

**mnist.yml**:

```
---
include:
  - mnist-defaults.yml
  - mnist_cnn_helper.yml

settings:
  cnn:
    k: 64
    s: 2

model:
  - input: images
  # - convolution:
  #     kernels: 64
  #     size: [2, 2]
  - cnn_block: "{{cnn}}"
  - activation: relu
  - flatten:
  - dense: 10
  - activation: softmax
    name: labels

train:
  data:
    - mnist:
        images:
          url: "http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz"
        labels:
          url: "http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz"
...
```

**mnist_cnn_block.yml**:

```
---
templates:
  cnn_block:
          - convolution:
        kernels: "{{k}}"
        size: "{{[s, s]}}"
...
```

**Here are the error message**:

```
> (dlnd-tf-lab)  ->kur dump mnist.yml
[ERROR 2017-03-29 09:02:11,789 kur.kurfile:734] Failed to read file: mnist_cnn_helper.yml. Check your syntax.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Natsume/Downloads/kur_road/kur/kur/kurfile.py", line 731, in parse_source
    data = Reader.read_file(expanded)
  File "/Users/Natsume/Downloads/kur_road/kur/kur/reader/reader.py", line 109, in read_file
    return reader.read(fh.read())
  File "/Users/Natsume/Downloads/kur_road/kur/kur/reader/yaml_reader.py", line 56, in read
    return yaml.load(data)
  File "/Users/Natsume/miniconda2/envs/dlnd-tf-lab/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 72, in load
    return loader.get_single_data()
  File "/Users/Natsume/miniconda2/envs/dlnd-tf-lab/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 35, in get_single_data
    node = self.get_single_node()
  File "/Users/Natsume/miniconda2/envs/dlnd-tf-lab/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 36, in get_single_node
    document = self.compose_document()
  File "/Users/Natsume/miniconda2/envs/dlnd-tf-lab/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 55, in compose_document
    node = self.compose_node(None, None)
  File "/Users/Natsume/miniconda2/envs/dlnd-tf-lab/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 84, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)
  File "/Users/Natsume/miniconda2/envs/dlnd-tf-lab/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 133, in compose_mapping_node
    item_value = self.compose_node(node, item_key)
  File "/Users/Natsume/miniconda2/envs/dlnd-tf-lab/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 84, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)
  File "/Users/Natsume/miniconda2/envs/dlnd-tf-lab/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 133, in compose_mapping_node
    item_value = self.compose_node(node, item_key)
  File "/Users/Natsume/miniconda2/envs/dlnd-tf-lab/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 64, in compose_node
    if self.check_event(AliasEvent):
  File "/Users/Natsume/miniconda2/envs/dlnd-tf-lab/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 98, in check_event
    self.current_event = self.state()
  File "/Users/Natsume/miniconda2/envs/dlnd-tf-lab/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 449, in parse_block_mapping_value
    if not self.check_token(KeyToken, ValueToken, BlockEndToken):
  File "/Users/Natsume/miniconda2/envs/dlnd-tf-lab/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 116, in check_token
    self.fetch_more_tokens()
  File "/Users/Natsume/miniconda2/envs/dlnd-tf-lab/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 257, in fetch_more_tokens
    self.get_mark())
yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning for the next token
found character '\t' that cannot start any token
  in "<unicode string>", line 4, column 1:
              - convolution:
    ^
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Natsume/miniconda2/envs/dlnd-tf-lab/bin/kur", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('kur', 'console_scripts', 'kur')()
  File "/Users/Natsume/Downloads/kur_road/kur/kur/__main__.py", line 382, in main
    sys.exit(args.func(args) or 0)
  File "/Users/Natsume/Downloads/kur_road/kur/kur/__main__.py", line 53, in dump
    spec = parse_kurfile(args.kurfile, args.engine)
  File "/Users/Natsume/Downloads/kur_road/kur/kur/__main__.py", line 45, in parse_kurfile
    spec = Kurfile(filename, engine)
  File "/Users/Natsume/Downloads/kur_road/kur/kur/kurfile.py", line 69, in __init__
    context=None
  File "/Users/Natsume/Downloads/kur_road/kur/kur/kurfile.py", line 754, in parse_source
    loaded=loaded
  File "/Users/Natsume/Downloads/kur_road/kur/kur/kurfile.py", line 731, in parse_source
    data = Reader.read_file(expanded)
  File "/Users/Natsume/Downloads/kur_road/kur/kur/reader/reader.py", line 109, in read_file
    return reader.read(fh.read())
  File "/Users/Natsume/Downloads/kur_road/kur/kur/reader/yaml_reader.py", line 56, in read
    return yaml.load(data)
  File "/Users/Natsume/miniconda2/envs/dlnd-tf-lab/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 72, in load
    return loader.get_single_data()
  File "/Users/Natsume/miniconda2/envs/dlnd-tf-lab/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 35, in get_single_data
    node = self.get_single_node()
  File "/Users/Natsume/miniconda2/envs/dlnd-tf-lab/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 36, in get_single_node
    document = self.compose_document()
  File "/Users/Natsume/miniconda2/envs/dlnd-tf-lab/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 55, in compose_document
    node = self.compose_node(None, None)
  File "/Users/Natsume/miniconda2/envs/dlnd-tf-lab/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 84, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)
  File "/Users/Natsume/miniconda2/envs/dlnd-tf-lab/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 133, in compose_mapping_node
    item_value = self.compose_node(node, item_key)
  File "/Users/Natsume/miniconda2/envs/dlnd-tf-lab/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 84, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)
  File "/Users/Natsume/miniconda2/envs/dlnd-tf-lab/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 133, in compose_mapping_node
    item_value = self.compose_node(node, item_key)
  File "/Users/Natsume/miniconda2/envs/dlnd-tf-lab/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 64, in compose_node
    if self.check_event(AliasEvent):
  File "/Users/Natsume/miniconda2/envs/dlnd-tf-lab/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 98, in check_event
    self.current_event = self.state()
  File "/Users/Natsume/miniconda2/envs/dlnd-tf-lab/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 449, in parse_block_mapping_value
    if not self.check_token(KeyToken, ValueToken, BlockEndToken):
  File "/Users/Natsume/miniconda2/envs/dlnd-tf-lab/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 116, in check_token
    self.fetch_more_tokens()
  File "/Users/Natsume/miniconda2/envs/dlnd-tf-lab/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 257, in fetch_more_tokens
    self.get_mark())
yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning for the next token
found character '\t' that cannot start any token
  in "<unicode string>", line 4, column 1:
              - convolution:
    ^
```

Comment: Please replace your screenshots with (formatted) text.

Comment: I seriously tried to use code format a number of times, but it was a mess. I used `{}` button, and also tried to indent, I also tried to just use ``` ``` , but not help at all. I also looked up the docs for using code format, but it seems not help in my case. I have no choice but use images.

Comment: Now, it works. but previously, when I add code below bullet points texts, the code format is a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that PyYAML (the YAML parser that Kur uses) silently ignores duplicate YAML keys, even though this is forbidden by the YAML spec. In fact, the [bug report](http://pyyaml.org/ticket/128) was filed 8 years ago, but hasn't been addressed yet (perhaps because it might break legacy code that relies on this behavior, but I'm not certain).

Since you said that "the rest of mnist.yml ... [is] untouched," I assume that you have an `include` key at the bottom of `mnist.yml`, since the last line of the off-the-shelf Kur example is:

```
include: mnist-defaults.yml
```

This is in conflict with the first line of your `mnist.yml` file, which now contains a duplicate `include` key. Instead, what you should do is replace both a single `include` section:

```
include:
  - mnist-defaults.yml
  - mnist_cnn_helper.yml
```

This should work as expected in Kur 0.5.2 or newer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have updated kur to 0.5.2 and made the change as you suggested, but still got some error. I have pasted the full code and the error above in the question section, as it seems I can't paste images in comment.

Comment: There are two problems with your edited code. The one that Kur is complaining about is an indentation problem in `mnist_cnn_helper.yml`, line 3, where `- convolution` is indented to the wrong level (maybe a tab problem in your editor? YAML only uses spaces). The second problem is that you include `mnist_cnn_helper.yml`, but in your edited question you titled the file `mnist_cnn_block.yml`, so just make sure the file names are consistent.